# How do I tell what version of Windows XP a license is good for?

Tags: windows-xp, license

My buddy's computer is not working. I want to re-install windows on it, but I'm not sure what version of Windows XP (home, pro, etc) the license sticker on it is good for. Is there a way I can tell? I don't want to go through the pain of installing it only to have it tell me that the code is invalid for the version I installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `%windir%\system 32\eula.txt` file. Scroll to the bottom of the document. If the old installation is unavailable, then you can't tell if it's been rubbed off the sticker. I'm on my cell, but I asked a similar question that I'll link to later

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that the version (Professional, Home, etc) is printed on the license sticker :P Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The codes are specific to various versions, as you know. If you couldn't find that eula.txt, or if that does not exist, or was incorrect...

Simply start typing the first few digits into google, along with the word "windows xp", or just windows, if you are unsure if it is actually XP or not.

When you search, it will show TONS of serials, and identify which OS variant it belongs to. (Note: The serial on some stickers is NOT the actual one you need to enter. If it is an OEM version, that number is just gibberish and will not activate any version. It is an OEM cross-reff number that only the OEM distributor can use to spit-out your actual activation-code, which often requires a specific OEM version of the software. OEM is not just one type of software, it is an indicator of WHO has the actual rights to the software, which is not you, it is them. HP, Dell, Compaq, Gateway, Bilbo-Computers, etc...)